# r - how to find the first empty bin of a histogram

Tags: r, histogram

I have a large dataset with response times. I need to make reference to the first empty bin of the histogram (with `x` being milliseconds), and exclude all data that comes after that.

I think

Can anybody help?

Comment: Could you share your data? See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That makes it a lot easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you capture the return of `hist` it contains all of the information that you need.

```
set.seed(3)
x = rnorm(20)
H = hist(x)

min(which(H$counts == 0))
[1] 5
```

To exclude the data that bin and above

```
MIN = min(which(H$counts == 0))
x = x[x<H$breaks[MIN]]
```